# NodeJS não respeita tabela de horário de verão do SO

Tags: node.js, data, timezone

Defini o meu timezone no nodejs para America/Sao_Paulo. Mas ele não respeita as tabelas do sistema operacional.

Eu utilizo o Ubuntu 18.04 LTS + NodeJS V10. O método `getTimezoneOffset` do `Date` me retorna o offset 120 (-2) ao invés de 180 (-3). Como posso fazer para corrigir o problema e fazer o método `getTimeZoneOffset` respeitar a tabela do S.O? Ou então como posso estar definindo o timezone manualmente até que eu solucione o problema.

Exemplo `teste.js`:

```
process.env.TZ = 'America/Sao_Paulo';
console.log(new Date().getTimezoneOffset()); // retorna 120 não 180
```

Node: v10.16.0

Comment: Como o problema foi encontrado, a conversa daqui foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100653/discussion-on-question-by-hiago-souza-nodejs-nao-respeita-tabela-de-horario-de-v)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De acordo com [pesquisa do autor da pergunta](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100653/), é um bug da tabela de TZ do Node.js. A solução é modificar o código temporariamente até que se possa pegar versão corrigida.

Link: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/30211

Comment: se quiser incrementar, eu coloquei o seguinte código para resolver temporariamente (primeira linha do entrypoint `index.js` do meu projeto): `process.env.TZ = 'America/Fortaleza';`

Comment: Ai é muita gambiarra kkkk. Se fosse GMT-3 ainda vai.... GMT-3 ao menos é determinístico (logo mais deleto o comment)

Comment: rss.. Então não achei nenhuma maneira de colocar o GMT-3 de forma genérica kkkk também não curti muito não, mas de momento está assim até encontrar outra solução (logo mais deleto também o comment kkk)